# Apply background color to li but not the nested ones

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have nested ul/li's and the problem is that if you add a background color to the top li, because there are nested items within it the whole list appears to have this background color rather than just the top li (I assume this is because it's extending the height of the top li).

Is it possible to only apply the background color to the top li?

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're speaking of the top `li`, but I think you mean the root `li`, which has child elements containing `li` elements as well. In that case, you can set the background color as follows:

```
.myroot>ul>li { background-color: Yellow }
```

Note: the sample above requires a wrapper element (usually a `DIV`) with the class name "myroot".

See [this article](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector) for more about CSS child selectors.

Answer (score 3):

There is the relationship selector `>` which means "immediate children":

```css
ul > li {
    background-color: <your color>;
}
```

This usually gets higher precedence than the rule expressed without `>`. This means the `ul > li` block's properties will override the ones in the `ul li` block.

---

### Now-Obsolete Workaround

***Note:** Back when this answer was first written in 2010, Internet Explorer 6.0 still had a huge market share. I've kept this part of the answer to help any programmers who may be stuck in the past.*

I have had problems with cross-platform compatibility while using the immediate child notation (IE6 doesn't support it). What you can do to work around that is set up multiple levels of rules:

```css
ul li {
    background-color: <your color>;
}

ul li li {
    background-color: none;
}
```

Comment: the second option is better since IE6 doesn't support the ">" child selector

Comment: @Jonathan That is exactly what I meant by "but I have had problems with cross-platform compatibility while using it."

Comment: no worries, I thought you were referring to Windows vs Linux vs Mac.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you have a UL with LI in it (let's call it 'parent'), and that LI also has a UL with LI (let's call them child) in it? You apply the background to the parent and it's also visible under the child?

As the child are located INSIDE the parent they must change his height, so the background is bigger than tought, there is 2 way to block that, you could (as mentionned earlier) put another background the the child, or you could put something like a SPAN inside the parent and put the background on the SPAN instead of the LI.parent.

Answer (score 0):

well you can always apply a different background colour to the child li's.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery and give a special class to the first li

```
`$("ul li:first")`.addClass('special_bg')
```

= get only the first <-li->  element of the <-ul->

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your CSS. You could define a top-level li class and use that to set the background colour.

Answer (score 0):

Children always inherit attributes from the parents; that's why it's called *Cascading* Style Sheets.

I suggest to give all `li` elements a default background color and just override it for the top level elements (for example with a special class).